# Extension method generic VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, extension-methods

I have a problem converting a method extension from VB.NET to C#, here is my working VB.NET code:

```
Module ClientBaseExtensions
    Private Const HDR_TOKEN = "Token"

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Initialize(Of T As Class)(ByVal client As ClientBase(Of T), url As String, pToken As String, pDeviceId As String)
        client.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(url)
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Item(HDR_TOKEN) = pToken
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = httpRequestProperty
    End Sub
End Module
```

When converting it automatically it gives me this code which is not recognized in my clientbased object

```
static class ClientBaseExtensions
{

    private const  HDR_TOKEN = "Token";

    public static void Initialize<T>(ClientBase<T> client, string url, string pToken, string pDeviceId) where T : class
    {
        client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Item(HDR_TOKEN) = pToken;
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = httpRequestProperty;

    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so whats the actual problem with this code?

Comment: The first parameter should be `this ClientBase<T> client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, extension methods are declared by specifying the `this` keyword for the first parameter (the one which defines the type that is extended):

```
static class ClientBaseExtensions
{

    private const  HDR_TOKEN = "Token";

                           // insert this here
    public static void Initialize<T>(this ClientBase<T> client, string url, string pToken, string pDeviceId) where T : class
    {
        client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);
        httpRequestProperty.Headers.Item(HDR_TOKEN) = pToken;
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = httpRequestProperty;

    }
}
```